# Base AWS IAM role on other role and extend it

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

Is it possible to have one role be based on another role in AWS IAM? The idea is to 
1. create a role that has wide access to a variety of resources
2. create a second role that is based on the first one but with more restrictive permissions

The use case I believe is rather common. The second role is used in the daily CICD operations to deploy new applications on the infrastructure and update resources using terraform. The first one is the the "sudo" version of the daily variant which is also allowed to delete S3 buckets, kafka clusters etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't possible. I like to check [CloudFormation pages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) to see which parameters I can assign to a resource when I create it. These are the current parameters:

```
Properties: 
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument: Json
  ManagedPolicyArns: 
    - String
  MaxSessionDuration: Integer
  Path: String
  PermissionsBoundary: String
  Policies: 
    - Policy
  RoleName: String
```

So there isn't possible to extend a Role to another. But if helps you, you may create a common policy to your roles and change the [boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) of each one.